# How to set height automatically for iframe in Angular 14?

Tags: css, angular, iframe, angular14

I want Iframe tag to be set height by 100% of its content.

In HTML file, I have:

```
<div *ngIf="linkSearch && linkSearch.link" class="row">
    <iframe *ngIf="!linkSearch.error" scrolling="no" class="iframe_{{linkSearch.title}}" id="iframe_{{linkSearch.title}}" [src]="getSafeUrl(linkSearch.link)" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

In component.ts file, I have:

```
ngOnInit() {
  setTimeout(() => {
     this.setHeightForIframe();
  }, 600);
}

public getSafeUrl(url: string): SafeResourceUrl {
   return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
}

public setHeightForIframe(): void {
     const iframe = document.getElementById(`iframe_${this.linkSearch.title as string}`) as HTMLIFrameElement;
     if (iframe) {
        iframe.style.height = `${iframe.contentWindow?.document.body.scrollHeight}px`;
        console.log(this.linkSearch.title)
        console.log(iframe.contentWindow?.document.body.scrollHeight);
     }
}
```

I have tried some way but it did not work in my case:

- 
- Use `iframe.addEventListener("load", () => { this.setHeightForIframe() }, false)`
- CSS for iframe (display, height, position...)

Does anyone know the solutions for this case?
Here is some links i use in iframe: https://mazii.net/vi-VN, jisho.org, ejje.weblio.jp, tratu.soha.vn.

Note: I open all links as tab component at one time and it really load all links.

Comment: you dont have control over IFrame's content, its a security feature implemented by browsers known as the "same-origin policy". If you have control over the IFrame it can send back it's height.

Comment: So I can't set height automatically in this case unless I have permission(contact them)? Or have any solutions for this?

Comment: They can't just "give you permission" in a way that would circumvent the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) in the browser; this needs _coding_ on both sides, that works together. The iframe needs to measure its own content height, and then report that value back to your page - the latter part is usually done using [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. If you know what content will be inside the iFrame you can use the follow way:

##### HTML

```
 <div *ngIf="urlSafe" class="html-data" [style.height]="height + 'px'">
    <iframe
      (load)="onHtmlDataLoad($event)"
      [src]="urlSafe"
      frameborder="0"
    ></iframe>
  </div>
```

##### TS Component

```
height: number = 0;

.....

  /** Hide the scrollbar of the iFrames content and set to full height to it */
  onHtmlDataLoad(event: any) {
    const iFrameElement = <HTMLIFrameElement>event.srcElement;

    const articleElement = iFrameElement.contentDocument?.getElementsByTagName('article'); 
    const headerElement = iFrameElement.contentDocument?.getElementsByTagName('header'); 
    const footerElement = iFrameElement.contentDocument?.getElementsByTagName('footer'); 

    if (articleElement && headerElement && footerElement) {
      this.height = 0;
      for (let el of Array.from(articleElement)) {
        this.height += el.offsetHeight;
      }
      for (let el of Array.from(footerElement)) this.height += el.offsetHeight;
      for (let el of Array.from(headerElement)) this.height += el.offsetHeight;

      this.height += 42 + 20; //Buffer for padding (footer = 42, body = 20)

      if (iFrameElement.contentDocument?.body) {
        iFrameElement.contentDocument.body.style.overflowY = 'hidden';
      }
    }
  }
```

I set a `height` variable to a div. This height will be calculated in the components typescript file. In my case there are `article`, `header` and `footer` tag element in the content of the `iFrame`. I search this elements, get the current height of their and calc a complete height which I set to the `iFrame` (or its outer `div`).

You can add some `css` in the public `styles.scss` to make it fix that the `iFrame` will use the complete height of its parent `div`

```
iframe {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  // position: absolute; // if needed
}
```

Comment: In my case, when I use onload in Iframe like you, the content of Ifram will reload infinitely and not thing inside function work. (Look like you press F5 consecutively reload your page)

Comment: `onload` is an event which will fire if the content is loaded. If your page will refresh it will be a other problem.

Comment: I mean just content of Iframe which has onload will be refresh, not all page.